# Is it considered polite in Switzerland to send a follow up email if I didn't hear from the potential employer?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, email-etiquette, switzerland

I've done an online job interview on Aug 27 for a job in the medical field in Switzerland.
I think I did a good impression and the interviewers told me they would update me in a month or so. I've heard from some friends who applied for similar positions that they would send an email clearly stating if you're granted or not the job. I still haven't received any update since the interview day.

Luckily enough I'm in a field with a lot of job opportunities, however the one I'm describing is my first choice. I'm under a lot of pressure from other companies to accept to work for them: in particular, if I'm not getting the job in Switzerland I would like to accept another job in an EU country but their offer will expire soon, since they want me to sign the contract as soon as possible (and I'm already trying to procrastinate).

First of all, it seems strange to me not having heard from them in almost 45 days, especially because we are talking about Switzerland. Is it a good idea/considered polite to write a follow up email asking for update? Also, since I would really love this opportunity I would add a short paragraph stating my motivation to work for them (maybe they haven't took a decision yet and they could appreciate)?

In my mind "a month or so" means "in less than 2 months", so I'm planning to write an email at 50 days from the interview day. Also I feel obliged to do so since it's not fair to keep waiting the other companies for long.

Comment: It's really bad form on the company's part to leave you hanging for 45 days without a reply one way or the other.  I'd assume that they have no interest and they are likely not a good employer either because they didn't even have the courtesy to say, "thanks but no thanks".  Move on to one of the companies that did offer you a position.

Comment: I'll add that telling you it might take 30 days is a long time but at least they set the expectation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: I'm not adding an answer because I don't really answer your question, but I'd say it doesn't matter if it's polite or not. You can't keep waiting for an answer that may come up or not, you need to take action, and this in general. I clearly can't see why it would be impolite or why would I like to work with people that believe that asking for information/clarification for a life-changing process is rude. Ask them for feedback, state the delay and that you have another offer so you would like to make a decision based on the complete information. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work in Germany in IT, and I believe the working culture is somehow close to Switzerland in IT at least, so I will share my experience with you:

- **In my experience at least**, asking employers for their decision about my application after some time from the interview(around a week or two) has always been beneficial. Even at my current job, if I haven't nudged the HR representative to give me an update, I don't think I would have got it. I discovered later on that they are always overwhelmed with applicants, and mine was in the long pipeline. The managers wanted me, but communication is very slow between departments.
- **I usually send a thank-you email for updates anyway.** I do it after a week from interviews I liked, and usually the response is positive. Unless you are interviewing for a top-tier company that are known to hate clingy applicants, anyone would appreciate having a thank-you email in their inbox.
- ***However***, sending such an email can be a **double-edged sword**. If you sounded too desperate, addressed someone wrong or came off too strong, you will probably hurt your chances.

Comment: I can second that. Had multiple companies I was waiting an answer from and the first one I called almost immediately hired me. When I later switched Jobs it was almost the same. "We will have the last interview on tuesday and tell you on wednesday". They never called. But the one job I called after about a week of waiting time, again, took me immediately when I asked if they made a decision because I am awaiting their answer. Also in Europe.